# Find the last row Index of a column where value is present in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I Have a table as below. I need to get the Index of last row where the value is present for Column B. In this case, it should return 14.

[image]

Please note that even if there is empty space on the column this should return the row number of last row where value exits in that column.

Comment: Go to the cell which contains "Item" (A8), then press Ctrl+Arrow down, go  one cell to the left, check if it's blank. If yes, press Ctrl+Arrow up, if not, just stay on that cell.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test ()
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Sheet1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '<= Make sure that you use the right sheet

End Sub
```

Comment: This throws an error at keyword End

Comment: @user3428508 try now.